# image gallery next and previous button

Tags: jquery, image

check this http://jsfiddle.net/5VEeH/

[img] is small picture and [a] is big pictures for display.
I want copy link from [a] href and that link be display image in '#display' div. next and previous button working and after last image start again from first picture.

Comment: don't just ask for do your job. show us what you've tried, what you've got and what problems you've encountered so far. then we'll help you.

Comment: If it is too complicated make next button to work, everything will be fine. i'm beginner with jquery and i try everything i know. i don't have more idea. If You do not help me i will find some ready-made script.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure I understand what you are looking for, but maybe this is it ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var E = $("a", "#img-list"), N = 0, T = E.length-1;

    $("#display").html('<img src="'+$(E[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
    $('#next, #prev').on('click', function() {
        var A = this.id == 'next',X=A?T:0,Y=A?0:T,Z=A?N+1:N-1;N=N==X?Y:Z;
        $("#display").html('<img src="'+$(E[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
    });
    E.on('click', function(e) {
        var S = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#display").html('<img src="'+S+'" />');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5VEeH/3/) to show it works!

Comment: wokr perfect. thank god for you exist :)

Comment: Wow , i wish i can write a short and smart code like you, you make me so amazing and know more about powerful of jquery. Look my code , it so bad and stupid :)

Comment: Well no, not really, your code looks fine to me, and I write code like that all the time. When writing a funcion or something it's often an advantage to be able to read the code and understand what's going on later. My example above just uses a lot of one letter variables and condensed if / else statements, and that is why it looks more complicated and more packed together, that's all really.

Comment: Your code works really well, but because it's so condensed it's very hard to see how I could use with two image galleries in one page. I've forked it here, but haven't made much progress: http://jsfiddle.net/cbp9T/1/

Comment: @Ali - I'm not really sure how to use it with two galleries, but you will probably have to create one more instance or make the code more "plugin like" to call it twice. It was written this way as more of a joke, and it's a good example of how not to write code that should be readable to others, with nested ternary statements and varibables with no recognisable name, just a letter.

Comment: Here it is as two galleries, for the curious: http://jsfiddle.net/sZqXs/ The generosity of StackOverflow knows no bounds! It has indeed been re-constructed to be more plugin-like.

Comment: @Ali - There you go, that's nicely done, and my hat off to you sir for figuring out that terribly condensed piece of code I wrote. Now half a year later even I don't get that code anymore by just looking at it, If I could upvote more, I would !!!

Comment: Wish I could take the credit, but it wasn't me! The person who wrote it, kei, answered my question asking for help with it, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800096/how-could-this-jquery-slider-with-prev-next-buttons-be-used-on-two-galleries-in/11801255#comment15681531_11801255 Upvote there!

Answer (score 0):

This is my version , for beginer . And i m beginner too :)

http://jsfiddle.net/5VEeH/6/

JS

```
$(function() {

    $('#listimg img').each(function(i){
    var img = $(this);
    img.attr('num',i).attr('id','img'+i);
     img.click(function(){
     $('.active').removeClass('active');
     img.addClass('active');
     $('.display').hide().attr('src',this.src).fadeIn();
     });
    });

    $('#img0').addClass('active');
    $('.display').hide().attr('src',$('#img0').attr('src')).fadeIn();

        $('#next').click(function(){
      var imgnext = $('.active');
      var idnext = Number(imgnext.attr('num'))+1;
      var last= $('#listimg img').length;
       if(idnext==last){}
                else{
      var srcn = $('#img'+idnext).attr('src');
     $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#img'+idnext).addClass('active');
            $('.display').hide().attr('src',srcn).fadeIn();}

     });
            $('#prev').click(function(){
      var imgnext = $('.active');
      var idnext = Number(imgnext.attr('num'))-1;
                if(idnext=="-1"){}
                else{
                      var srcn = $('#img'+idnext).attr('src');
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
       $('#img'+idnext).addClass('active');
       $('.display').hide().attr('src',srcn).fadeIn();}


     });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="display"> <img class='display' src="" /></div>
    <button id="prev">prev</button>
    <button id="next">next</button>
<div id='listimg'>
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tGWtjEA6S-0/Tr3KpPLtLSI/AAAAAAAADaY/VBCrqP1_Gm8/-c/" />
    <img src="http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/47/img1td.png" />
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tGWtjEA6S-0/Tr3KpPLtLSI/AAAAAAAADaY/VBCrqP1_Gm8/-c/" />
    <img src="http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/47/img1td.png" />
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tGWtjEA6S-0/Tr3KpPLtLSI/AAAAAAAADaY/VBCrqP1_Gm8/-c/" />
    <img src="http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/47/img1td.png" />


</div>
```