# How could this JQuery slider with prev/next buttons be used on two galleries in one page?

Tags: jquery, button, slider

Based on this great image slider with prev/next buttons by adaneo, in this answer here: [image gallery next and previous button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924862/image-gallery-next-and-previous-button)

His JSFiddle is here, and it does what I need it to do, except that I need it to work on two separate galleries in the one page:
http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5VEeH/3/

Here is my forked JSFiddle, which I haven't done much to except duplicate the mark-up:
http://jsfiddle.net/cbp9T/1/

How could I re-write that so that I could use it twice in one page? Would I make the whole thing it's own function, killing the variable values at the end, and then duplicate it into a new function with new selectors for the 2nd gallery? Or?

Suggestions/links to JSFiddles that answer a problem like this extremely gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: So you want 1 set of controls to control both galleries?

Comment: Nope, 2 galleries, each with their own controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create unique IDs for `display`, `next`, `prev`, and `img-list` as well as styling each `display` in CSS.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sZqXs/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        gallerify: function(o) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = "#" + this.id;
                var E = $("a", o.imgList), N = 0, T = E.length-1;
                $($this).html('<img src="'+$(E[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
                var btns = o.next.concat(",",o.prev);
                $(btns).on('click', function() {
                    var A = this.id == (o.next).substr(1,o.next.length),X=A?T:0,Y=A?0:T,Z=A?N+1:N-1;N=N==X?Y:Z;
                    $($this).html('<img src="'+$(E[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
                });
                E.on('click', function(e) {
                    var S = $(this).attr('href');
                    $($this).html('<img src="'+S+'" />');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);


$("#display").gallerify({imgList:'#img-list',next:'#next',prev:'#prev'});
$("#display2").gallerify({imgList:'#img-list2',next:'#next2',prev:'#prev2'});
```